# This is the inputlist input_list =[1,0,3,2,0,1,0] and I want output_list as [1,1,2,3,0,0,0] How to solve this?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

```
input_list =[1,0,3,2,0,1,0]

for a in input_list:
    if input_list[a] != 0:
        input_list[a] = a 
    else:
        input_list[a] = 0
        
print(input_list)
```

**Tried this but getting output as input_list =[1,0,3,2,0,1,0]
Instead i want this [1,1,2,3,0,0,0]**

```
for a in input_list:
    if input_list[a] != 0:
        input_list[a] = a 
    else:
        input_list[a] = 0
        
print(input_list)
```

Comment: DO you want to sort the list, but putting 0 last?

Comment: Yes, But without using sorting methods.

Comment: You want to sort without sorting? :-)

Comment: Yes. Without sorting methods.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to write your own sorting functionality rather than using the built-in methods?

Comment: Yes.  Own sorting functionality  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> getting output as input_list

No, your code gives `[0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 1, 0]`, because you use the values as indexes, `for a in input_list` iterates over values, then you use them `input_list[a]` as indexes

---

What you need is sorting, `x or float('inf')` expression takes `inf` in case the value of `x` is 0 (putting it at the end of the list), else it takes the value of `x`

```
input_list = [1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0]
result = sorted(input_list, key=lambda x: x or float('inf'))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a custom sort where you give `0` infinite weight so it appears at the end of the sorting order.

```
output_list = sorted(input_list, key=lambda x: x if x != 0 else float('inf'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_list =[1,0,3,2,0,1,0]
input_list.sort()
new_list = [el for el in input_list if el != 0] + [el for el in input_list if el == 0]
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: `new_list = sorted([el for el in input_list if el != 0]) + [el for el in input_list if el == 0]` help sorting a smaller list

Comment: Bravo!! I'll fix this

Comment: also "tail list" as `[0] * input_list.count(0)`. Further, `list.sort` acts `in-place`

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way to solve this is:

```py
import math
input_list =[1,0,3,2,0,1,0]

input_list = sorted(input_list, key=lambda x: x if x!=0 else math.inf)
```

Which is sorting like one would usually do, but giving the `0` a weight of `inf` (infinite) such that it's always the last item.

Answer (score 0):

There are already some good answers, here is just one more alternative approach, albeit more *concise and little tricky:*

Here it's use the "True" and "False" of each number and its identity to move all "True" (number is zero) to the end of list.

```py
L = [1,0,3,2,0,1,0]

ans = sorted(L, key=lambda x: (x ==0, x))

print(ans)
[1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```

If you don't want to create a new list, you can use the same list as this way:

```
L[:] = sorted(L, key=lambda x: (x ==0, x))
```